# Discrete to continuum: differentiating a summation and finding its maxima

Tags: summation, maxima-minima

While playing around with statistical moments, I came around the following sum
$$
\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
$$
which motivated
$$
f(n)=\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n~ i^{1/n}
$$

To my surprise, it seems to peak at some point (**we are interested in finding that point**):

[image]

and holds when I make the steps smaller and smaller:

[image]

I intuited that in the continuous limit,
$$
\begin{align}
f(n)&=\frac{1}{n-1}\int_{1}^{n}x^{1/n}dx\\
&=\frac{n(n^{1+1/n}-1)}{n^2-1}
\end{align}
$$

which is ugly but holds:

[image]

and has a hopeless derivaitve that roots at $3.12831\ldots$, which seems about right. **Is there a way to have found out the maxima (numerical or analytic value) without having to convert to the integral first?**

Comment: Lookup [summability calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5739) to generalize sums to continuous functions.

Comment: $f(n)=\frac{H_n^{(-1/n)}}{n}$. Lookup harmonic numbers as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aaron Hendrickson already commented, using generalized harmonic numbers
$$f(n)=\frac 1 n H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$ and the maximum is reached for $n=3$ for which $f(3)=\frac{1}{3} \left(1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}\right)\sim 1.23406$. This is very easily obtained using integer optimization.